# What is this curved surface constructed inside a rectangular prism?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, surfaces, geometric-construction

Given is a rectangular prism with one side $\square ABCD$ and its opposite side $\square EFGH$. Point $J$ lies on $\square ABCD$ some distance $y$ between diagonal $AC$ and edge $AB$, and point $K$ lies on $\square EFGH$ $y$ between diagonal $EG$ and edge $GH$. The midpoint of line segment $JK$ is the exact center of the prism (i.e., it is also the midpoint of diagonal $AG$), but $JK$ need not be perpendicular to any side of the prism.

Draw curve $AJC$ on side $\square ABCD$ and curve $EKG$ on side $\square EFGH$, so that the curves are geometrically similar. Now you have a curved surface, $AEGC$, with opposite straight sides $AE$ and $GC$, and opposite curved sides $AJC$ and $EKG$. Stipulate also that all points on $JK$ lie on this surface, as do all points on the line segment between the midpoint of $AE$ and the midpoint of $GC$.

What is this three-dimensional, curved surface? Does it have a name and general equation? Possibly an application or analog in real life? If not, how can one find the equation?

Edit: These are images of the surface.

[image: The surface]

[image: Also the surface]

Comment: You're using words like above and below and top side. Those depend on how the diagram is drawn. Are $ABCD$, $EFGH$ vertical? If so are $AC$, $EG$ horizontal?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is an example of a [ruled surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) along a straight line.

Comment: A sketch would *really* help here.

Comment: @Chrystomath: You're right! I'll edit to make it not dependent on direction, but yes, I was envisioning that $A$ was in the top left-hand corner and then $BCD$ continue clockwise around the remaining vertices. The opposite side is clockwise from $E$.

Comment: Is "rectangular prism" the same for you as "rectangular parallelepiped" (shoebox)? Besides, please, add a figure !

Comment: @virtuolie Can you please confirm that the inserted image corresponds to the description of the surface?

Comment: @Chrystomath: Thank you! Your image was very nearly it, but my description was ambiguous on one point (the surface fits entirely inside the prism) and wrong on another ($JK$ does not necessarily lie on a line perpendicular to a side of the prism). I've edited to clarify/correct. I added the images at commenter's request. Also, yes, it's definitely a ruled surface, but I can't find a known ruled surface that flattens out at each end.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yes, it's a rectangular cuboid. I'm most interested in the special case of the square cuboid in the image.

Comment: @virtuolie: This is my interpretation: As point $J$ *traces a curve* from $A$ to $C$ in $ABCD$, the point $K$ (defined by reflecting $J$ in the center of the prism) *traces an identical, but reoriented, curve* in $EFGH$. The target surface appears by joining points on these curves in *reverse tracing order*; ie, parameterizing $J=J(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq1$, with $K=K(t)$ the reflection of $J$, the surface is the union of segments $\overline{J(t)K(1-t)}$. Is this close? ... Without reverse-tracing, the surface is of course a cone; I don't know a name for the reversed version ... "anti-cone"? :)

Comment: @Blue: Yes, that sounds like it's exactly what I have in mind.

Comment: Once again, a question of vacabulary : "square cuboid" = "cube" (plainly) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my interpretation of the construction, confirmed by OP in a comment to the question:

> As point $J$ *traces a curve* from $A$ to $C$ in plane $ABCD$, the point $K$ (defined as the reflection of $J$ in the center of the prism) traces an identical, but reoriented, curve in plane $EFGH$. The target surface appears by joining corresponding points on these curves in *reverse tracing order*; ie, parameterizing $J=J(t)$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$, with $K=K(t)$ the reflection of $J(t)$, the surface is the union of segments $\overline{J(t)K(1−t)}$.

Without reverse-tracing, the surface is, of course, a cone; I don't know a name for the reversed version ... "anti-cone"? :)

---

Now, for a prism with its center at $M$ (so that $\frac12(J(t)+K(t)) = M$), we can parameterize a point $P=P(s,t)$ on the surface by

> $$P(s,t) = (1-s) J(t) + s K(1-t) = (1-s) J(t) + s(2M-J(1-t)) \tag{1}$$

So $P(0,t)$ traces the defining curve of $J$, while $P(1,t)$ traces the reflected curve. Note that there's no particular reason here to restrict the defining curve to a plane.

With $M$ conveniently at the origin, $(1)$ reduces to

> $$P(s,t) = (1-s) J(t) - s J(1-t) \tag{1'}$$

Some examples ...

- If the "curve" is merely a *segment* joining, say, $J_0$ to $J_1$ (OP's $A$ and $C$), then
  $$J(t) = (1-t) J_0 + t J_1 \tag2$$ and $(1')$ becomes
  $$\begin{align}
  P(s,t) &= (1-s) ((1-t) J_0 + t J_1) - s (t J_0 + (1-t) J_1) \\[4pt]
  &= J_0 - s(J_0+J_1)-t(J_0-J_1)
  \end{align} \tag{3}$$ giving the plane through $J_0$, $J_1$, and the origin.
- If $J_0 = A=(p,p,r)$ and $J_1 = C=(-p,-p,r)$ (giving our prism a square face) and the curve is a semicircle in the plane $z=r$, then
  $$J(t) = (0,0,r) + (p,p,0) \cos \pi t + (p,-p,0)\sin\pi t \tag4$$
  and we have the cylinder
  $$P(s,t) = (1-2s)\;\left(\;p (\cos\pi t + \sin \pi t), p (\cos\pi t - \sin\pi t), r \;\right) \quad\to\quad x^2 + y^2 = 2 p^2 \tag{5}$$
- More generally, we can replace $\cos\pi t$ in $(4)$ with any $f(t)$ such that $f(0) = -f(1) = 1$, and $\sin\pi t$ with any $g(t)$ such that $g(0)=g(1)=0$. How far we can get in eliminating the parameters depends upon the exact nature of $f$ and $g$.
   For, say, $$f(t) = 1-2t \qquad g(t) = 2t(1-t) \tag{6}$$ we obtain this cubic surface
  $$z(x+y)^2 + 4 p ( r x - r y - p z ) = 0\tag{7}$$ Here's a rendering with $p=r=1$:

[image]

---

In response to a comment: One can solve $(7)$ for, say, $x$ using the [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to get
$$x = \frac{-2 p r - y z \pm 2 \sqrt{p^2 r^2 + 2 p r y z + p^2 z^2}}{z} \tag{7'}$$
For points restricted to the prism, we take the "$\pm$" to be "$+$".

Comment: Your interpretation is surely the good one.

Comment: Excellent! My first question is: Which dimensions are x, y, and z? I ask because, when I assumed z was the axis on the top right (the one with a negative slope from this perspective), I plugged in x and y and got something very close to but not quite your picture (or mine): the top and bottom of the surface were not flush with the vertices, as though the surface had been rotated slightly clockwise. So I'm inferring that I need to solve for x or y, but with the quadratic term, the solution is not obvious. So my second question is, how do I get the function into a form set equal to x or y?

Comment: Also, you mentioned not knowing what this shape is relative to a cone. I can tell you this: If you take one of the three dimensions (the one I want to solve for, call it x) and subtract it from y (the axis perpendicular to the top square of the prism as pictured), then the curved edges become the branches of a hyperbola, and the lines ruling the surface become the family of lines tangent to both branches.

Comment: @Blue: Actually, I figured it out. If I have the equation for the curve, I can solve for the 3 coordinates of P and Q, such that the line PQ goes through the point of interest. Plug any 2 coordinates of that point into the equation for that line to get its 3rd point.

Comment: @virtuolie You should accept the version of Blue. You will not get a better one.

Comment: @virtuolie: I've added a labeled figure, and I solved equation $(7)$ for $x$ as an example. Note that, as mentioned in the answer, "How far we can get in eliminating the parameters [that is, expressing the surface as an $xyz$ relation] depends upon the exact nature of $f$ and $g$". ... Regarding your hyperbola comment: The kinds of curves ones sees also depend upon $f$ & $g$. Importantly, not only the $J$ curve's shape *but also its specific parameterization* matters. Note that the $(7)$ example corresponds to a third-degree $xyz$ eqn, so most plane curves within it are *cubics*, not conics.

Comment: @Blue: Thank you! You have provided an even more general solution than I expected. The constraints on possible functions f and g are unfortunate, but what can you do.